# Virtualenvwrapper not found

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-module, virtualenvwrapper

Given what I know about Python, the problem I'm having shouldn't been happening.  I installed virtualenvwrapper on Mac OS X Snow Leopard with pip.  It's there in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages.  But when I try to import virtualenvwrapper, Python tells me there's no such module with that name.  Other modules (e.g. virtualenv) load just fine, and /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages is right at the top of my Python path.  So is there something weird about virtualenvwrapper so that Python isn't finding it?

Comment: Looking around some more, some people seem to be having the same problem if they have multiple versions of Python installed.  If I try `mkvirtualenv -p python2.6` or `mkvirtualenv -p python2.7` I get the same module-not-found error.  How do I figure out which Python was used to install virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Mine is in /usr/local/bin/virtualwrapper.sh but you should be able to add this to your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or .profile to put into your environment. (Remember to do source .bashrc or open a new terminal window)

```
source /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

*EDIT* Here's my entire bash profile related to pip, virtualenv and virtualenv wrapper since it looks ugly as a comment

```
# python
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python:$PYTHONPATH

export PATH=/usr/local/MacPorts/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/MacPorts/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

#virtualenv wrapper
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs

# mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages myenv
source /usr/local/MacPorts/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is not with the shell script but with the Python package itself.  I have `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in my .bash_profile, but on opening a new terminal window I get:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.'

Comment: So despite everything seeming to be set right in .bash_profile, it's giving me this module-not-found error, which is what lead me to trying to import the module directly in Python, and finding that it still couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing virtualenvwrapper with `**sudo** pip virtualenvwrapper`.  It might be referring to the shell script it installs in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Mac OS X 10.9.2 with XCode 5.1.1 and for me `virtualenvwrapper.sh` file was present in

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

So I simply copied this into `~/.profile` file:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And now my `~/.profile` file looks something like this:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-23_at_17:28:39: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And now I am able to use `virtualenvwrapper` commands without any issue whatsoever

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```